# Download File with modem Quectel EM-12

Tags: command, at-command, quectel

I recorded and saved an audio clip (.wav) inside the UFS memory of the Quectel modem (version EM-12).
I would like to copy the clip contained in the modem to my local PC.
How can i do?
Using the command AT + QFDWL = "clip.wav" I only get a binary data output and not the file download.
Thanks to those who will be able to help me

Comment: What serial terminal do you use? You have to tell it to "capture" the binary data you get.

Comment: I'm using hyperterminal. I get binary data that by storing them inside a txt file I can't convert it to wav correctly. How can I do?